# Difference between JDBC and JPA/Hibernate in JProfiler

Tags: jprofiler

[image]

I'm using `JProfiler` to check database payloads. I want to know difference between `JPA/Hibernate` and`JDBC` in JProfiler. Image attached with question show `JPA/Hibernate` took `208ms` and `JDBC` took `44,679 us` does it mean that hibernate took `164 ms` to process data? Is it correct?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is correct. Hibernate can ad quite some overhead.

Comment: Hey Thanks for the information. Do you have any solution to reduce the time taken by hibernate. As you've gone through so many projects, I guess.

Comment: You could have a look at setting up a second level cache in hibernate. It really depends on what you are doing in detail, though.